# How to make Raspberry shutdown when I unplug the ethernet cable

Tags: raspbian, power, server, script, ethernet-port

I use my Raspberry Pi Model B with Raspbian as a server and I want to know (if it is possible) how to make that the Raspberry pi send itself a halt command when I unplug the Ethernet cable (eth0)

Any help will be very appreciated.

Comment: Why? If you unplug it won't work! Why halt - to save 5w? The solutions below would work, but would also halt on router glitches.

Comment: True, so is there any way to detect if it's "physically" unplugged from eth0?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**post-down script;**

Write a script to call 'reboot' as **/path/to/script.sh**

Edit your **/etc/network/interfaces** file and add a line just below your eth0 config.

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
name "Ethernet0"
address 192.168.1.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
broadcast 192.168.1.255
network 192.168.1.0
gateway 192.168.1.254
post-down /path/to/script.sh
```

Your **/path/to/script.sh** script will run when your **eth0** down.

Comment: Don't encourage people to periodically poll for events! Your second option is a lot better, you say for yourself - so why don't remove your first option?

Comment: @Bex you're right.

Comment: This is valid for older Raspbian versions, like wheezy. For buster, there's a directory of scripts that you can just drop your shutdown script into. I edited this answer to add this, but someone rejected the edit (!?). See my answer if you're on buster.

Answer (score 0):

### For recent Raspbian builds (like Buster)

Just drop your shutdown script into the `/etc/network/if-post-down.d` directory. Remember to make the script executable, as well.

```sh
#!/bin/sh

/sbin/shutdown -h now
```

Comment: Just on recent versions of Raspbian/Debian you should avoid using deprecated *ifupdown networking*. Instead systemd unit files should be used.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, @ingo. Do you have a pointer to a working examples? The first couple pages of search results were people asking for systemd help and failing.

Comment: [Make ifplugd available again since Raspbian Stretch](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/96604/79866).

Answer (score -1):

Create a cron job every minute to ping your gateway, the moment the ping is lost- issue halt command. You can check for example for 2 consecutive pings to be sure is not a glitch.

Comment: when your router reboot or down also your RPi will reboot?

Comment: You should _never_ periodically poll for an event!

Comment: can you explain why not polling

Comment: @jet Because 1) it consumes resources unnecessarily, and 2) it is inherently slow.

Comment: if you don't poll - the kernel's scheduler is doing it for you (every 100mS, I am doing it once per minute). The only nonpolling events are interruptions, everything else is polling somewhere.