# How to make Raspberry shutdown when internet/lan disconnected

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, pi-2, raspbian-stretch, shutdown

I've already seen this link [How to make Raspberry shutdown when I unplug the ethernet cable](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/22822/how-to-make-raspberry-shutdown-when-i-unplug-the-ethernet-cable), but this solution does not work on Raspbian stretch since its network interface file/folder structure is changed.

My Raspberry pi is headless and battery powered (assume that it will give backup around 10min), so whenever electricity is gone for long time I want it to shutdown properly. Also note that when electricity goes down my network also goes down, so can't use ssh.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got a better solution... I've used the lan connection for internet and configure the wifi as AP using the following link https://github.com/SurferTim/documentation/blob/6bc583965254fa292a470990c40b145f553f6b34/configuration/wireless/access-point.md

Then connect to the AP using mobile (android) with any ssh client and send the shutdown command to shut it down properly.

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT 2**: You can use a dhcpcd exit hook script. The script is called on each dhcpcd event and checks the reason for calling dhcpcd and the related interface.

Create the script /etc/dhcpcd.exit-hook (usually it doesn't exists, otherwise edit it):

```
if [ "$reason" = NOCARRIER ] && [ "$interface" = eth0 ]
then
  echo "$(date) - eth0 DOWN, will shutdown now" >> /log/eth0_shutdown.log
  poweroff
fi
```

Note that this script file doesn't need to have a first line like `#!/bin/bash` and it also doesn't need to be set as executable.

Create the folder /log if it doesn't exists

```
sudo mkdir /log
```

---

Edit 1: If a cron job is too slow, then a while loop may be used instead. Adjust the sleep time as required.

```
#!/bin/bash

while [ $(cat /sys/class/net/eth0/operstate) == "up" ]
do
  sleep 10
done
echo "LAN is down, will shutdown now"
poweroff
```

---

First answer

You can monitor the interface status with a script which is regularly called by a cron job.

```
if [ $(cat /sys/class/net/eth0/operstate) == "down" ]
then 
   echo "LAN is down, will shutdown now"
   poweroff
fi
```

Answer (score 4):

use `post-up` and `post-down` hook options in network script `/etc/network/interfaces` ,

you can create a simple script for shutdown, lets call it `sd.sh` executing which system will be shut down, so your network interfaces script will look like

```
# For static IP, consult /etc/dhcpcd.conf and 'man dhcpcd.conf'

# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
wpa-roam /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
iface default inet dhcp
    post-down ~myPath~/sd.sh
```

Comment: This may be OK - provided you don't mind breaking the standard Raspbian `dhcpcd` networking.