# Make ifplugd available with systemd

Tags: networking, systemd

On networking I often need to know when a connection is complete established with an ip address or if it gets down. In the past this was done with the classic daemon **ifplugd**. The Debian package for it  uses old style **ifupdown** managed with `/etc/network/interfaces`. But since Raspbian Wheezy 2015-05-05 **dhcpcd** is used for networking instead of **ifupdown**.

How can I make **ifplugd** available again for Raspbian without using **ifupdown**?

Comment: @Milliways I have corrected the version in the answer. Thanks. And yes you are right, `ifplugd` is still in the Buster repository. I haven't said that it isn't. Otherwise I wouldn't be able to download it. Have you realized my question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**ifplugd** is running as daemon so we have to use a **systemd** service to manage it. I will only use the daemon program `/usr/sbin/ifplugd` without the management scripts from Debian.

Tested with
[Raspberry Pi OS 2020-12-02](https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspios_armhf/images/raspios_armhf-2020-12-04/) based on Buster on a Raspberry Pi 4B updated at 2020-05-12.
[Raspbian Stretch Lite 2019-04-08](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/) updated at 2019-04-16.
Updates done with `sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade && sudo reboot`.

### Install ifplugd program

First we download the **ifplugd** package but don't install it, only extract the daemon program:

```
rpi ~$ apt download ifplugd
rpi ~$ ar -p ifplugd_*_armhf.deb data.tar.xz | sudo tar -xJ -C / ./usr/sbin/ifplugd
rpi ~$ rm ifplugd_*_armhf.deb
rpi ~$ ifplugd --version   # at the time testing this
ifplugd 0.28 (SVN: 124)
```

### Create new service for the ifplugd program

We will not run **ifplugd** as classic daemon. Instead we run it as service and do not have to "daemonize" it. Look at the man page [<sup>**(1)**</sup>](https://linux.die.net/man/8/ifplugd) that we have to use option `--no-daemon`. Other options are used to disable functions that are managed by **systemd** now. Create the new service with:

```
rpi ~$ sudo -Es
rpi ~# systemctl --full --force edit ifplug@.service
```

In the empty editor insert these statements, save them and quit the editor:

```
[Unit]
Description=Interface plug monitor (interface-specific version)
Documentation=https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/96605/79866
After=sys-subsystem-net-devices-%i.device

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/ifplugd --iface=%i --no-daemon --no-auto --no-syslog --no-beep --no-shutdown --run=/etc/ifplugs/ifplugs.action

[Install]
WantedBy=sys-subsystem-net-devices-%i.device
```

### Create Action Script

As described in the man page [<sup>**(1)**</sup>](https://linux.die.net/man/8/ifplugd) the service calls a script on every event **up** and **down** on an interface. Here I will use a template. Create this action script with your editor:

```
rpi ~# mkdir /etc/ifplugs
rpi ~# editor /etc/ifplugs/ifplugs.action
```

In the empty editor insert these statements, save them and quit the editor:

```
#!/bin/bash
# redirect all output into a logfile for debug
#exec 1>> /tmp/ifplugs-debug.log 2>&1

INTERFACE="$1"
EVENT="$2"
IPADDR=''

get_ipaddr () {
    if [ "$EVENT" = "down" ]; then
        IPADDR=$(/sbin/ip -4 -br addr show $INTERFACE | /bin/grep -Po "\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+")
        return 0
    fi
    # check 10 times with 1 sec delay if ip address is available
    for ((i=10; i>0; i--)); do
        IPADDR=$(/sbin/ip -4 -br addr show $INTERFACE | /bin/grep -Po "\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+")
        [ $? -eq 0 ] && break
        /bin/sleep 1
    done
}

case "$INTERFACE" in
eth0)
    case "$EVENT" in
    up)
        # do stuff on connect with interface
        get_ipaddr
        echo "$INTERFACE" up with ip address \""$IPADDR"\"
        ;;
    down)
        # do stuff on disconnect with interface
        get_ipaddr
        echo "$INTERFACE" down with ip address \""$IPADDR"\"
        ;;
    *)
        >&2 echo empty or undefined event for "$INTERFACE": \""$EVENT"\"
        exit 1
        ;;
    esac
    ;;

wlan0)
    case "$EVENT" in
    up)
        # do stuff on connect with interface
        get_ipaddr
        echo "$INTERFACE" up with ip address \""$IPADDR"\"
        ;;
    down)
        # do stuff on disconnect with interface
        get_ipaddr
        echo "$INTERFACE" down with ip address \""$IPADDR"\"
        ;;
    *)
        >&2 echo empty or undefined event for "$INTERFACE": \""$EVENT"\"
        exit 1
        ;;
    esac
    ;;

*)
    >&2 echo empty or unknown interface: \""$INTERFACE"\"
    exit 1
    ;;
esac
```

Make it executable:

```
rpi ~# chmod +x /etc/ifplugs/ifplugs.action
```

`/usr/sbin/ifplugd` needs an own instance for every interface. So we start them with the interface-specific version:

```
rpi ~# systemctl start ifplug@eth0.service
rpi ~# systemctl start ifplug@wlan0.service
rpi ~# exit
rpi ~$
```

If you want to start the ifplug.service on boot up, just enable it:

```
rpi ~$ sudo systemctl enable ifplug@eth0.service
rpi ~$ sudo systemctl enable ifplug@wlan0.service
```

Now the actions `up` and `down` for each monitored interface are logged to the journal. Follow it with

```
rpi ~$ journalctl --follow

# You may filter it with:
rpi ~$ journalctl --follow | grep ifplugd
```

You are free to modify `/etc/ifplugs/ifplugs.action` or create your own. If you want to monitor other interfaces then just use its interface names for the interface-specific services and in the action script instead of **eth0** and **wlan0** in this example.

**References:**
(1): [man page ifplugd](https://linux.die.net/man/8/ifplugd)

Comment: I just tried this protocol, and while everything looks like it deploys, I'm getting log messages about missing shared library libdaemon on service start. This is on Buster 2020-12-02, with latest updates applied. What's best? Install from sources? Or is there a better way?

Comment: @StuartWatt Is`libdaemon` the exact name of the missing library? Do you see the log message in the journal with `journalctl -b`?

Comment: Thanks for the crystal-clear instructions. @Ingo This works really well and helps to plaster over what was previously what /etc/network/interfaces. Learnt something new with the %i arguments in the unit files too. I would buy you a beer if you were nearby!

Comment: @lackdaz drinking a beer would be a good idea but its a bit complicated with corona restrictions ;-)