# How to toggle wifi based on Ethernet connection?

Tags: networking, raspbian-jessie, ethernet, wireless

I've tried a dozen different searches, but nothing has turned up exactly what I need.  Here's my use case:

[Minimally at boot, bonus if dynamically]

1. If Ethernet has (or obtains) link, configure Ethernet up and wifi down (so no
   bonding, no prioritizing Ethernet over wifi that requires wifi to also be up):

   1. Stop openvpn-server@myvpn .
   2. Bring wlan0 down, and disable it.
   3. Bring eth0 up.
2. If Ethernet does not have (or loses) link:

   1. Enable wlan0 and bring it up.
   2. Start openvpn-server@myvpn .

I *think* the default solution (Raspbian based on Debian Jessie on my Pi 2) is mostly there; it runs ifplugd, and doesn't appear to have systemd-networkd installed or running.  ifplugd exits, though, instead of running as a daemon.  So I might be able to add a script in /etc/ifplugd/action.d/ that would take care of the VPN shutdown.  I just need to be sure it's disabled so it doesn't start up while the Ethernet is connected.

TIA for any help!

Answer (score 2):

You can create a `bash script` with this code content and create a `systemd unit file` where you call the bash file in `ExecStart`, enabling the unit at boot and using `systemctl start yourunit` and `systemctl stop yourunit` commands whenever. See the commented lines :

```
#!/bin/bash 

# Configure the variables
ETHIF="eth0"
WLANIF="wlan0"
# check ETHIF link every 5 seconds
NEXTCHECK=5

while : 
do

   ETHIP=$(ip -f inet -4 a show dev $ETHIF|grep inet|awk -F ' ' '{print $2}'|awk -F '/' '{print $1}')
   ETHISUP=$(ip -f link a show $ETHIF | grep -o "state UP")
   ETHHAVEROUTE=$(ip r show dev $ETHIF)

   WLANIP=$(ip -f inet -4 a show dev $WLANIF|grep inet|awk -F ' ' '{print $2}'|awk -F '/' '{print $1}')
   WLANISUP=$(ip -f link a show $WLANIF | grep -o "state UP")
   WLANHAVEROUTE=$(ip r show dev $WLANIF)

   # 1 If Ethernet has (or obtains) link
   if [ ! -z "${ETHIP}" ]&&[ ! -z "${ETHHAVEROUTE}" ];then

      # 1-a Stop openvpn-server@myvpn .
      systemctl stop openvpn-server

      # 1-b Bring wlan0 down, and disable it.
      if [ ! -z "$WLANISUP" ];then
         ip link set $WLANIF down
      fi;

      # 1-c Bring eth0 up.
      # If you have a route and an IP address on the interface ,the ETHIF is already UP          
      #if [ -z "$ETHISUP" ];then
      #   ip link set $ETHIF up
      #fi;

   # 2 If Ethernet does not have (or loses) link
   else

      # 2-a Enable wlan0 and bring it up.
      if [ -z "$WLANISUP" ];then
         ip link set $WLANIF up
      fi;

      # 2-b Start openvpn-server@myvpn .
      systemctl start openvpn-server

   fi;

   sleep $NEXTCHECK
done
```

Comment: Thank you!  I'll give that a try and see how it works.  Since something is configuring the interfaces now, I need to make sure it gets disabled so this is the only "network manager" running.

Answer (score 2):

I would say **ifplugd** is the right daemon to solve your problem. But the Debian package for it uses old style *ifupdown* managed with `/etc/network/interfaces`. Since Raspbian Stretch *dhcpcd* is used for networking instead of *ifupdown* so support for **ifplugd** is also "deprecated". I think to use a complete outdated Raspbian version **Jessie** only for this issue is not a good idea. With an unsupported operating system you will run into trouble more and more with the time. You should better modify **ifplugd** to run on current Raspbian versions. How to do it you can look at [Make ifplugd available again since Raspbian Stretch](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/96605/79866). With some scripting knowledge it should not be a problem to modify `/etc/ifplugs/ifplugs.action` shown in that answer to meet your requirements.